# GWT flextable set different width for each column

Tags: java, gwt, flextable

Hi guys Is possible set a different width for each column in a flextable ?

Answer (score 5):

The HTMLTable.ColumnFormatter will help you set individual widths to columns of your FlexTable. To get the formatter instance, call [`getColumnFormatter()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLTable.html#getColumnFormatter%28%29).

If you are using external CSS stylesheets, using the formatter's [`setStyleName()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLTable.ColumnFormatter.html#setStyleName%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) method will let you assign style names per column. Once a style name is set, assign CSS `width` rules to it.

If you're setting the widths programmatically, the [`setWidth()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLTable.ColumnFormatter.html#setWidth%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) method of the formatter will let you assign column widths in your GWT code (hat tip to Thomas Broyer).

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Nothing. If the programmer wants to externalize the CSS rules for columns and then change them without rebuilding the app the style name approach would do it. To be honest though I simply glossed over the `setWidth` method when reading the Javadoc :)

Comment: You might want to update your answer with the alternative then.